# Adding column to aspnet_users table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using aspnet db for my usermanagement.I added a column named companyID to the aspnet_Users table.Also altered the coresponding stored procedures.I want  to pass the companyID to the database when i click on the createUser Button. Currently showing some error that the procedure expect the parameter @CompanyID.How can i save the companyID to the aspnet_users table by an effective methode.
I am using ASP.net 2010 with VB.
Please help to resolve the problem.Thanks in Advance..